# Move default docker postgres data volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-volume

I've created a docker postgis container with the following command :

```
docker run -p 5435:5432  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="-d" mdillon/postgis:9.6
```

This created a volume for data in /var/lib/docker/volumes/[some_very_long_id]/_data

Now I need to move this volume to somewhere else to ease backup for my outsourcing contractor... and don't know how to do this. I'm a bit lost as there seems to be different alternative with data volumes and fs mounts for example.

So what's the correct way to do it as today ? And how to move my current data directory to a better place ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a volume mount when you run your container. For example, you could run your container like this:

```
docker run -p 5435:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx -e POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS="-d" \
-v /the/path/you/want/on/your/host:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
mdillon/postgis:9.6
```

This way the postgres data directory will be in the `/the/path/you/want/on/your/host` in your host.

Comment: Yes that's the "fs mount" way I mention I my question. But I didn't start the container this way, and do not want to re-create a container and loose data. So how to move the already created volume ?

Comment: I guess you can't rename volumes. Your best bet IMHO is to run a dump, restart the container with the new volume mounted and restore data. You're going to have a small downtime though.

Comment: Yes i guess that's my best option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check or search deeply, but in your case I suggest to do following step:

1. Create another container with outside folder.
2. Using `pg_basebackup` get all data from the old container to the new container. Or using replicate.

So, you have the data folder outside the container.

Hopefully it will help your case.

Comment: I was hoping for a more straightforward procedure such as moving and renaiming the volume, but will do a good ol backup as you suggest if nothing else comes up. Thanks for the tip diden't know pg_basebackup